# Passport Js / Express - How to choose which part of the user object will be part of the req object?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using passport Js for auth, on Node Js / Express app.

the problem occurs with big user obj (which i know is related to my data schema , but thats another issue)  , which are always a part of the request Obj, and it makes the app much slower for such users.

is there any solution that can prevent the full user (req.user) Obj to be sent in each request?
i couldn't find any info about it online.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change what is saved to `req.user` in the `deserializeUser` function.

Comment: does this mean that every time a request is sent, this function loads the user?